# Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cors

As I open up my frontend in the Chrome browser the two errors below keep on popping in my console.
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://hog.simplify.jobs/decide/?v=3&ip=1&_=1688782636903&ver=1.57.2' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

```
POST https://hog.simplify.jobs/decide/?v=3&ip=1&_=1688782636903&ver=1.57.2 net::ERR_FAILED 404 contentScript.bundle.js:1
```

I've tried to add the extension [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) but it does not help. Also, I've tried to update my code into this

```
app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));
```

or this

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

in my backend side code. However, both code do not work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access this website from the front end as it is a security issue. Instead, you will need to do this on the backend with a library such as [Axios](https://axios-http.com/).

You can see more about why this is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors#)

Comment: Sorry! I'm not following. Could you please give me an example of how to update my frontend Vue.js code?

Comment: I’m not familiar with Vue.js, but basically you can’t make requests to that url from the front end.

Comment: But my frontend is set up on this url...

Comment: But you are testing on local host so it is technically two separate urls.

Comment: Yes, My frontend is set on localhost: 8080 and my backend is set on localhost: 4000. What's the problem with having different urls if I already set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to '*'? Could you explain the problem in detail?